# Tag added each questions

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Today I have checked some user added "magento-1" tag in all Magento 1 related question. I have little confusion for further approval this type of edit.

In Magento stack exchange lot of Magento 1 related question is there.

Further, I need to approve this suggestion edit? please clarify.

Comment: I also rejected those edits, If you feel something more can improve in post then reject those

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Thanks, Further i have rejected this type of edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the related edits, but ...

- if the question had no version tag
- is definitly related to M1 only (screenshots, code)
- is not tagged with another `magento-1.x` tag

... it is absolutly correct. (IMHO)

Comment: i provide example https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/137996 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/138007

Comment: @RamaChandranM both correct imho. 2013 and one with relation to `MagentoConnect`.

Comment: He did on Oct 02 more than 20 edits like this.  so only this question  ask.

Comment: @RamaChandranM You can only do 20 edits a day ... so why not, it doenst hurts. Every question should have a version tag.